# Error during building/compiling "Hello World" for Android

Tags: java, android, netbeans, compiler-errors, windows-xp-sp3

I have a compiling problem. I followed tutorial about "Hello world" program for Android and I've managed to compile and run the program successfuly a couple of times. But the next day when I turned on computer, I tried to run the program again and it gave me the following error:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\sh0ne\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloAndroid\build.xml:83: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:65: taskdef A class needed by class com.android.ant.NewSetupTask cannot be found: com/android/sdklib/ISdkLog using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\anttasks.jar]".
```

When I searched the Internet (and also StackOverflow.com), all I found is discussions about "taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found" problem, but that doesn't help as I don't have that error. I've checked my paths (local.properties, build.xml, path to Andoid SDK) and everything seems fine (yesterday everything worked like a charm, since then I didn't touch/change anything and now I cannot build/run the app). I tried "Clean and Build", it gives me the same error.

I am using Netbeans 7.0.1 with nbandroid plugin (7.0+). I installed Android 4 (API 14) and Android 2.2 (API 8). It gives me the same error for both. I am running Windows XP SP3.

Source Code:

```
package org.brokenbyte.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android!");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

And here is the complete debug output:

```
Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
Detected OS: Windows XP
Adding reference: ant.ComponentHelper
Trying to override old definition of task java
 +Datatype java org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.ForkedJavaOverride
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-ant-browsetask.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/ant/browsetask/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-ant-browsetask.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/ant/browsetask/antlib.xml from a zip file
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype nbbrowse org.netbeans.modules.ant.browsetask.NbBrowse
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-ant-browsetask.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/ant/browsetask/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-ant-browsetask.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/ant/browsetask/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.ant.browsetask:nbbrowse org.netbeans.modules.ant.browsetask.NbBrowse
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/profiler/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-profiler.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/profiler/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/profiler/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-profiler.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/profiler/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype nbprofileattach org.netbeans.modules.profiler.ant.NBProfileAttachTask
 +Datatype nbprofiledirect org.netbeans.modules.profiler.ant.NBProfileDirectTask
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/profiler/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-profiler.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/profiler/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/profiler/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-profiler.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/profiler/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.profiler:nbprofileattach org.netbeans.modules.profiler.ant.NBProfileAttachTask
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.profiler:nbprofiledirect org.netbeans.modules.profiler.ant.NBProfileDirectTask
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/apisupport/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-apisupport-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/apisupport/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/apisupport/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-apisupport-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/apisupport/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype nbinstaller org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.ant.InstallModuleTask
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/apisupport/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-apisupport-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/apisupport/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/apisupport/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-apisupport-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/apisupport/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.ant:nbinstaller org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.ant.InstallModuleTask
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/debugger/jpda/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/debugger/jpda/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype nbjpdaconnect org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAConnect
 +Datatype nbjpdastart org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAStart
 +Datatype sourcepath org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAStart$Sourcepath
 +Datatype nbjpdareload org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAReload
 +Datatype nbjpdaappreloaded org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAAppReloaded
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/debugger/jpda/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/debugger/jpda/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant:nbjpdaconnect org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAConnect
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant:nbjpdastart org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAStart
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant:sourcepath org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAStart$Sourcepath
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant:nbjpdareload org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAReload
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant:nbjpdaappreloaded org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.ant.JPDAAppReloaded
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-javawebstart.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/javawebstart/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-javawebstart.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/javawebstart/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype jnlpsignjars org.netbeans.modules.javawebstart.SignJarsTask
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-javawebstart.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/javawebstart/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-javawebstart.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/javawebstart/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.javawebstart:jnlpsignjars org.netbeans.modules.javawebstart.SignJarsTask
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-java-source-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/java/source/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-java-source-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/java/source/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Trying to override old definition of task javac
 +Datatype javac org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask
 +Datatype translate-classpath org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.TranslateClassPath
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-java-source-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/java/source/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/NetBeans%207.0.1/java/ant/nblib/org-netbeans-modules-java-source-ant.jar!/org/netbeans/modules/java/source/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant:javac org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask
 +Datatype antlib:org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant:translate-classpath org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.TranslateClassPath
Setting ro project property: ant.file -> C:\Documents and Settings\sh0ne\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloAndroid\build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.version -> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Setting ro project property: ant.home -> C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0.1\java\ant
Setting project property: ant.junit.enabletestlistenerevents -> true
Setting ro project property: build.compiler.emacs -> true
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.parsing.context
Adding reference: ant.targets
parsing buildfile C:\Documents and Settings\sh0ne\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloAndroid\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/sh0ne/My%20Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloAndroid/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.project.name -> HelloAndroid
Adding reference: HelloAndroid
Setting ro project property: ant.project.default-target -> help
Setting ro project property: ant.file.HelloAndroid -> C:\Documents and Settings\sh0ne\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloAndroid\build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type.HelloAndroid -> file
Project base dir set to: C:\Documents and Settings\sh0ne\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloAndroid
 +Target: 
Adding reference: ant.LocalProperties
Setting project property: sdk.dir -> C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
Loading C:\Documents and Settings\sh0ne\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloAndroid\ant.properties
Setting project property: target -> android-8
Importing file C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml from C:\Documents and Settings\sh0ne\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloAndroid\build.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
Adding reference: ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/Program%20Files/Android/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file. -> C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml
Setting ro project property: ant.file.type. -> file
 +Target: all
 +Target: clean
 +Target: -setup
 +Target: -build-setup
 +Target: -pre-build
 +Target: -code-gen
 +Target: -pre-compile
 +Target: -compile
 +Target: -post-compile
 +Target: -obfuscate
 +Target: -dex
 +Target: -crunch
 +Target: -package-resources
 +Target: -package
 +Target: -set-mode-check
 +Target: -set-debug-files
 +Target: -set-debug-mode
 +Target: -debug-obfuscation-check
 +Target: -do-debug
 +Target: debug
 +Target: -release-prompt-for-password
 +Target: -release-nosign
 +Target: -release-obfuscation-check
 +Target: -set-release-mode
 +Target: release
 +Target: -set-instrumented-mode
 +Target: instrument
 +Target: emma
 +Target: -test-project-check
 +Target: test
 +Target: install
 +Target: installd
 +Target: installr
 +Target: installi
 +Target: installt
 +Target: uninstall
 +Target: help
Setting project property: adb.device.arg -> 
Setting project property: android.package.excludes -> 
Setting project property: version.code -> 
Setting project property: version.name -> 
Setting project property: aapt.resource.filter -> 
Setting project property: java.encoding -> UTF-8
Setting project property: java.target -> 1.5
Setting project property: java.source -> 1.5
Setting project property: verbose -> false
Adding reference: android.antlibs
Finding class com.android.ant.NewSetupTask
Loaded from C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\anttasks.jar com/android/ant/NewSetupTask.class
Class org.apache.tools.ant.Task loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class com.android.ant.NewSetupTask loaded from ant loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Object loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class java.lang.Throwable loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Class org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
Finding class com.android.sdklib.ISdkLog
C:\Documents and Settings\sh0ne\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloAndroid\build.xml:83: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:65: taskdef A class needed by class com.android.ant.NewSetupTask cannot be found: com/android/sdklib/ISdkLog using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\anttasks.jar]
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:234)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:163)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:65: taskdef A class needed by class com.android.ant.NewSetupTask cannot be found: com/android/sdklib/ISdkLog using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\anttasks.jar]
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:239)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:169)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:225)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdklib/ISdkLog
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.addDefinition(Definer.java:594)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.sdklib.ISdkLog
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1311)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1064)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 25 more
```

I don't understand what happened. Please help.

PS: Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining your log file clearly shows that class com.android.sdklib.ISdkLog is not in classpath of Ant. This causes problem that class com.android.ant.NewSetupTask is not found.

It seems that either android SDK is not installed on you machine or at least ant tasks that are used to build android project are not in classpath of Ant. I think that the second option is more relevant. In this case you should find appropriate jar file and add it to `ant/lib`.